# Como criar um cronômetro no JavaFX usando scene builder?

Tags: java, javafx

Galera, já estou há alguns meses com alguns projetos encalhados, por motivo de não conseguir que uma `label` fique se atualizando constantemente.

Consigo fazer um cronômetro, mas na hora de passar para a interface criada pelo *scene builder*, ele trava, pois não consegui atualizar o `label`, eu acho.

Por favor, me ajudem, estou precisando muito.

**Exemplo:**

```
package progrma.de.teste.nivel.pkg2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class interface2 implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    private int contador=0;
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

           Timer tm = new Timer();
            tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                contador++;
                int seg  =  contador %60;
                int min  =  contador /60;
                int hora =  min      /60;
                min     %=  60;
                label.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d:",hora,min,seg));
            }
        },1000,1000);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
            }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu consegui fazer de duas formas diferentes.

## Abordagem 1:

Usar uma Task normal e atualizar o label através de um bind com o messageProperty() da thread:

```
Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while(!isCancelled()){
            contador++;
            int seg  =  contador %60;
            int min  =  contador /60;
            int hora =  min      /60;
            min     %=  60;
            
            updateMessage(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hora,min,seg));
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        
        return null;
        }
    };
label.textProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
```

### Problemas:

As vezes *parece* ser mais lento que o esperado, não sei se por conta da comunicação entre o updateMessage e o bind, mas acredito pode ser ajustado mudando o tempo do sleep.

## Abordagem 2:

Utilizar o Platform.runLater() para forçar a atualização do label utilizando a Application Thread:

```
Timer tm = new Timer();
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                contador++;
                int seg  =  contador %60;
                int min  =  contador /60;
                int hora =  min      /60;
                min     %=  60;
                label.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hora,min,seg));
            }});
        }
    };
tm.scheduleAtFixedRate(task,1000,1000);
```

### Problemas:

2 run() aninhados não me parece ser uma boa prática de programação

**Avisos adicionais:**

- Ambas as soluções devem ser paradas manualmente pois as threads continuam executando após o encerramento da aplicação!
- Fica a critério do leitor usar a solução lhe pareça mais precisa, visto que as mensurações de performance são uma opinião pessoal, não fiz um teste comparativo das duas.

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Ao meu ver e, pelo q estou estudando, a abordagem 1 é a mais correta. Porém, é importante ressaltar pontos aqui: O 1º e principal é q para se inciar um Task é preciso da classe Servive, que herda de Sevice, no caso da abordagem 1, ficaria extends Service. Em 2º lugar é q em uma Task é q estão os métodos updateProgress(), updateMessage() e updateTitle() e alguns outros métodos q podem ser sobrescritos, como done(), cancelled(), failed() e alguns outros. O 3º e também, ao meu ver, importante, pela questão de boa prática de programação, é q a lógica toda para atualizar o tempo ficaria melhor se posta em um método, e, no método call() chamar esse método, que seria usar a prática de encapsulamento

Como sou novo por aqui ainda não tive tempo para ver da maneira adequada como fazer para postar um código, mas vou colocar do jeito como sei ( pretendo aprender bem como postar um código devidamente formatado )

Segue o código d um exemplo q fiz para o mesmo exercício:

```
public class UpdateService extends Service<String> {

private int segundo;
private int minuto;
private int hora;
private int contador;

private String path = getClass().getResource("/som_de_submarino.mp3").toString();

private Media media = new Media(path);

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);

@Override
protected Task<String> createTask() {
    return new Task<String>() {

        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {

            while (true) {
                cronometrar();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }


        }

        private void cronometrar() throws Exception {

            contador++;
            segundo = contador % 60;
            minuto = contador / 60;
            hora = minuto / 60;
            minuto %= 60;

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                if (minuto == (i * 10) && segundo == 0) {
                    mediaPlayer.play();
                }
            }

            if (hora > 0) {
                updateMessage(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hora, minuto, segundo));
            } else {
                updateMessage(String.format("%02d:%02d", minuto, segundo));
            }
        }

    };

}

public void setContador(int contador) {
    this.contador = contador;
}
```

}

Comment: No texto onde falei da classe Service não apareceu q ela herda de Service e o tipo de retorno. Ex: extends Service<void>

Comment: É uma outra forma de resolver mas aqui o principal é dar uma orientação. Usamos a classe Service quando existe no código alterações na UI, que só podem ser feitas pela FX thread e Task quando as operações são em background. Usar Task favorece o isolamento da FX Thread para renderização por esse motivo eu usei apenas Task e Bind para resolver este problema.

Comment: Além disso pode-se iniciar uma Task sem herança criando uma thread e associando a tarefa a ela, dessa forma: new Thread(task).start();

Comment: No modo como vc fez o exercício, vendo o código e o modo como uma Task foi criada, assumi-se q o código foi feito via programação. No exemplo q passei o exercício foi feito via arquivo FXML. Portanto, estou assumindo o fato de q uma classe Controller foi criada. Para completar minha solução basta instanciar um objeto da classe UpdadeService. ex: UpdateService service = new UpdateService() na classe Controller e no método initialize() da classe Controller criar um Bind tipo: label.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty());

Comment: No modo como vc fez o exercício, vendo o código e o modo como uma Task foi criada, conclui-se q o código foi feito via programação. No exemplo q passei o exercício foi feito via arquivo FXML. Portanto, estou assumindo o fato de q uma classe Controller foi criada. Para completar minha solução, basta instanciar um objeto da classe UpdadeService. ex: UpdateService service = new UpdateService() na classe Controller e no método initialize() da classe Controller criar uma Bind unidimensional tipo: label.textProperty().bind(service.messageProperty()); Apenas deixei d mencionar a Bind

Comment: Tbém gostaria d mencionar q, no exemplo q passei, da classe Service, o cronômetro está configurado p despertar a cada 10 minutos. Porém, do modo como está não funciona, é preciso colocar um outro if na método cronometrar depois do 1º for tipo: if (seconds == 30) { mediaPlayer.stop(); }. Dessa forma o cronômetro vai despertar a cada 10 minutos, ou como cada um quiser configurar

Answer (score 0):

Aqui eu faço assim...

```
    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        //Data atual do Sistema
        LocalDate hoje = LocalDate.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formataDia = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String diaAtual = hoje.format(formataDia);

        lblData.setText(diaAtual);

        Timeline relogio = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, e -> {

        //Data atual do Sistema
        LocalDateTime agora = LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter formataHora = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
        String horaAtual = agora.format(formataHora);

        lblHora.setText(horaAtual);

        }),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(1))
        );
        relogio.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        relogio.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


@FXML
private Label timerLabel;
private Timer timer;
private int seconds = 0;
```

Adicione o seguinte método para atualizar o Label com o tempo decorrido:

```
private void updateTime() {
    seconds++;
    timerLabel.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60)));
}
```

Adicione os seguintes métodos para iniciar e parar o cronômetro:

```
@FXML
private void startTimer() {
    if (timer == null) {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateTime();
            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }
}

@FXML
private void stopTimer() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}
```

Vincule os métodos `startTimer` e `stopTimer` aos botões "Iniciar" e "Parar", respectivamente, no Scene Builder.